# How many ways do we have to count $1$ to $100$ by adding $1$ or $2$ each time?

Tags: combinatorics

We count $1$ to $20$ and each time we add $1$ or $2$. For example, the numbers can be $1,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,15,17,19$ and $20$. How many ways do we have to count $1$ to $100$ by adding $1$ or $2$ each time?

Comment: Instead of starting with 20, see if you can identify a pattern for n=2,3,4,5,...

Comment: In your example, when you got to 17, were you then allowed to go to 19, and then to 21, or are you required to **land** on 20?

Comment: it is required to land on 20 only we can't go with 21

Answer (score 0):

This **hint** assumes that you must land squarely on 100.

You must have an even # of 1's to go with your 2's.

Therefore, as $k$ goes from 0 thru 50, you have $2k$ 1's.

You will have to do a summation.

Suppose that you had $2k$ 1's.

Then you must have **how many** 2's?

Suppose that you have $a$ 1's and $b$ 2's.

How many ways are there of arranging the $(a+b)$ steps?

Answer (score 0):

To generalize it, if you count from $1$ to $n$, let $f(n)$ denote the number of ways to do so (adding just $1$ or $2$ each time). The last number you add can be either a $1$ or a $2$, which means that before the last step, you have to have arrived at either $n-1$ or $n-2$. This leads to the recursion of the Fobonacci numbers:
$$f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)$$
Analyzing the initial values, we find that $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=1$, so you are looking for the $100^{th}$ Fibonacci number which should be
$$f(100)=354224848179261915075$$